# Container always reach same backend on replicated services

Tags: docker-swarm, grpc

I'm deploying a 3 tier application using docker swarm, similar to:

```
                           --> BACK01-01 --    --> BACK02-01
                           |              |    |  
 FRONTEND-01 ----------------> BACK01-02 --------> BACK02-02
                           |              |    |
                           --> BACK01-03 --    --> BACK02-03


  Frontend                  Back Service 01    Back Service 02
```

This is a 3 node swarm, where each `*-01` service task is running on the `manager-node`, each `*-02` service task is running on `worker-node-01` and each `*-03` service task is running on `worker-node-02`

All communication between services are using GRPC and creating a new connection per request.

All I want with this is to distribute the load over every replica.

Sequentially I made a request to `frontend` which make a request to `back01`, which make a request to `back02`. But after 50 requests, all inner requests where made to `back01-03` and `back02-03` and the other were never reached.

I using default service configuration and the stack was deployed using [portainer GUI](https://www.portainer.io/)

Is there anything that I'm not understanding?

P.S: I had tested service load balance with a simple HTTP and GRPC server returning the container id, with 4 replicas in one node, and it was returning each one sequentially.

Comment: How are your gRPC clients set up? Are they using a [round robin load balancing policy](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc/balancer/roundrobin)?

Comment: I'm using python on the client and c# on the server. The cliente make a request using a simple connection without extra configuration. [Like this](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/f1dfe791ab9730a1c7f1c32beb19eb72ff835e38/examples/python/helloworld/greeter_client.py#L29)